# How to make an element out of its parent's range?

Tags: html, css, layout, position

My HTML:

```
  <div id="main">
    <div id="inner_div"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  #main{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  #inner_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

As you can see, now `#main` will center in the page, I can't change the style of #main. I can change the style of `#inner_div`, I want to make it at the left of the page, so I change the CSS to:

```
 #inner_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index: 2012;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
 }
```

But #inner_div is still in `#main` 's range:
[image]
My question is, how could I change the CSS of #inner_div but not #main to make #inner_div break the bound of #main ? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9EYP6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use negative positioning parameters, e.g.

```
left: -10px;
top: -10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

@wong2; may you have to give `positon` in negative

```
#inner_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index: 2012;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: -10px;
 }
```